# DRF, queryset by a models choices field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django rest framework model:

```py
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

from Project_Level.CONSTANTS import AREAS


class KnownLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(name="Name",
                            unique=False,
                            max_length=150,
                            blank=False,
                            help_text="Enter the name of the location's name")

    area = models.CharField(name='Area',
                            max_length=8,
                            choices=AREAS)

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    latitude = models.FloatField(name="Latitude",
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)

    longitude = models.FloatField(name="Longitude",
                                  unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                  default=1)
```

```py
AREAS = [
    ('210', '210'),
    ('769', '769'),
    ('300', '300')
]
```

serializer:

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
from .models import KnownLocation


class KnownLocationSerializer(Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = KnownLocation
        fields = ('id', 'Name', 'Area', 'Latitude', 'Longitude')
```

I want to write a view with a query set ( maybe a get_queryset method will be better), where the query return all objects which has the same 'area' has the one past in by the user.

Answer (score 0):

in `views.py`

```
> @api_views (['GET']) def filterArea_KnownLocation(request, area):
>     locations = KnownLocation.objects.filter(area=area)
>     serializer = KnownLocationSerializer(locations, many=True, context={'request': request})
>     return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

in `urls.py`

```
path('KnownLocations/filter/area/<str:area>', views.filterArea_KnownLocation)
```

now for example, if you are using vue in front-end you can do the following:

```
getLocationsByArea(){
  this.$http
      .get("/KnownLocations/filter/area/210", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      })
      .then((res)=>{
        this.locations = res.data;
      });
```